# Too many dml rows:10001

Tags: soql

Too many dml rows:10001 - why is this error thrown when the maximum number of records SOQL can return is 50,000.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DML is different to SOQL.

SOQL is the query language used to return rows whereas DML is the process typically used to insert, update, upsert or delete records.

**Example SOQL**

```
List<Contact> c = [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact];
```

**Example DML**

```
Contact c = new Contact(
  FirstName = 'Foo',
  LastName = 'Bar',
  AccoundId = 'ABC123'
);

INSERT c;
```

As the [Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) say:

> Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries: 50,0000
>
> Total number of records processed as a result of DML statements, Approval.process, or database.emptyRecycleBin: 10,000

In other words, you're not hitting any SOQL limit, rather the DML limit. So when you say the SOQL limit is 50k, you're absolutely correct. But the error:

> Too many dml rows: 10001

Isn't thrown from any SOQL Governor Limit.

**Edit**
To answer your question (as I understand it at least, someone else may be able to give a clearer answer):

> How is 'Too many dml rows: 10001' different from 'System.Exception: Too many query rows: 10001' ?

"Too many dml rows: 10001" means you can't processes more than 10000 records from DML statements. The link to the governor limits page is pretty self explanitory:

> Total number of records processed as a result of DML statements, Approval.process, or database.emptyRecycleBin.

For instance, imagine you're updating records to change the companies contacts work for (as an example), you wouldn't able to do more than 10000 from DML statements. If you do, you hit the limit.

As for "System.Exception: Too many query rows: 10001". Check out [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xorIAA) question and answer on the Salesforce forums as it goes in to quite a bit of detail.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How is 'Too many dml rows: 10001' different from 'System.Exception: Too many query rows: 10001' ?

Comment: @mySFDC Check out my edit. :)